# How can I define a lot of variables at once

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project and would like to know if there's an easy way to define and use multiple variables without having to write a bunch of code.

So what I've been doing is just defining them all like this:

```
var Kahoot = require("kahoot.js-updated");
var client1 = new Kahoot;
var client2 = new Kahoot;
var client3 = new Kahoot;
var name = "example";
var id = "12345";
```

And then using them like this:

```
client1.join(id , name+"1").then(() => {client1.on("question", question => {});client1.on("questionStart", question => {question.answer(randomAnswer());})});
client2.join(id , name+"2").then(() => {client2.on("question", question => {});client2.on("questionStart", question => {question.answer(randomAnswer());})});
client3.join(id , name+"3").then(() => {client3.on("question", question => {});client3.on("questionStart", question => {question.answer(randomAnswer());})});
```

This works well, but I have to manually copy and paste, then replace the variable number. What is an easier way to do this without copypasting over and over?

Comment: [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array).

Comment: ([English version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of Wiktor's link) Arrays allow you to group all of your "same items" together, then you can loop through all items in the array and run the code for each, as opposed to hard-coding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```
var Kahoot = require('kahoot.js-updated');
var name = 'example';
var id = '12345';

var clients = new Array(3);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var client = new Kahoot();
  client.join(id, name + (i + 1)).then(() => {
    client.on('question', question => {});
    client.on('questionStart', question => {
      question.answer(randomAnswer());
    });
  });
  clients[i] = client;
}
```

Then the array `clients` contains your three clients.

Comment: Hmm, the coding site im using throws on line 2: `Parsing error: Unexpected token ":"`
Is this an error with the code or is the website incorrect?

Comment: @mjm0813 I think the foreach might use `in` rather than `:`. Google the syntax.

Comment: @mjm0813 Yes sorry I forgot that `for ... : ...` don't exist in js. I replaced it by `Array.prototype.forEach`. [There are a lot of ways to iterate on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) but `for-in` is not the most recommended and is even deprecated (@ago), use `for-of` instead.

Comment: When I run this code it is acting like its using the same variable (`example`) 5 times, not acting like its 5 different variables

Comment: There's a syntax error in the answer (`.then()({ ... })`), however the code functionally should be fine. @mjm0813, you'll have to provide your actual code, as evidently it seems something important may have been left out.

Comment: heres a [link to my project](https://glitch.com/~beryl-beanie). Its kinda a mess, the code related to this is in `randomAnswers.js`

Comment: @mjm0813 Please edit your question with the appropriate code. Though, I'd suggest finding a happy medium between a 5-line snippet that doesn't reproduce the issue and providing an entire repo. Your question is required to have a [**minimal**, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - unfortunately the two versions you've provided satisfy each case strictly individually.

Comment: @mjm0813 I edited my answer according to your edited question.